# Equation for rotated 2D flat-top Gaussian distribution

Tags: curve-fitting, distribution, gaussian, curve

I'm in need for an equation for rotated 2D flat-top Gaussian distribution.
What is my problem: I have data images that look like this (image on the left): [image: exemplary data]
What I'm trying to do is to fit a function to these data. My first approach was to fit rotated 2D gaussian distribution using this formula:

```
    sigx2 = sigma_x**2
    sigy2 = sigma_y**2

    a = np.cos(theta)**2/(2*sigx2) + np.sin(theta)**2/(2*sigy2)
    b = np.sin(theta)**2/(2*sigx2) + np.cos(theta)**2/(2*sigy2)
    c = np.sin(2*theta)/(4*sigx2) - np.sin(2*theta)/(4*sigy2)
    
    expo = -a*(x-x0)**2 - b*(y-y0)**2 - 2*c*(x-x0)*(y-y0)
    g = offset + A*np.exp(expo)
```

Unfortunately, as you can see in the image on the right, normal 2D Gaussian distribution is not steep enough, I need something that looks more like a rounded, less steep, uniform distribution. On wiki I've found an equation for flat-top gaussian:
[image: f(x,y)=A\exp\left(-\left(\frac{\left(x-x_0\right)}{2\sigma^2_X}\right)^{P_X}-\left(\frac{\left(y-y_0\right)}{2\sigma^2_Y}\right)^{P_Y}\right)]

I think it might work for me, unfortunately I don't know how to incorporate `theta` parameter into it so this distribution would be rotated. Can anyone help me modify my original formula in a way that it would give a flat-top distribution? Or modify wiki's flat-top gaussian formula by incorporating rotation parameter theta into it?

Comment: That's just a shift and rotation of the coordinate system. Nothing more.